# Vimeo get video id from custom video url

Tags: vimeo

Recently I came accross this Vimeo video url:  https://vimeo.com/moonstreetpictures/headabovewater

video does exist but its protected (not sure if its locked to domain or similar) but as you can see video id is a string.

Normaly I would use this regex to get video id (which of course doesnt work here).

```
 var regex = new RegExp(/(https?:\/\/)?(www.)?(player.)?vimeo.com\/([a-z]*\/)*([0-9]{6,11})[?]?.*/);

if ( regex.test(url) ) {
    return regex.exec(url)[5];
}
```

Is this naming convention documented somewhere on Vimeo? I dont want to make some regex because I dont know what I might expect.

Comment: What's the video ID?  Is the issue that your URL doesn't contain the ID, but when you access it, it changes to `https://vimeo.com/810951169`, and you want `810951169`?

Comment: Actually I dont know the ID url, I was given this url by my client.  The point was more where this url comes from (where its documented that video can have such url and how can the api use it ). My script failed to get video id because of such format.